# Grab an array within imported JSON object - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am building a quick Angular app that uses a service to grab a JSON from a URL.

The JSON structure looks like this:

```
{news:[{title:"title",description:'decription'},
       {title:"title",description:'decription'},
       {title:"title",description:'decription'}
      ]};
```

What I need is just the array within the news object.

My code to import the JSON is as follows:

```
app.factory('getNews', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('URL') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

Then to add the data to the $scope object in the controller I do this:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','getNews', function($scope, getNews) {
getNews.success(function(data)) {
    $scope.newsInfo = data.news;
    });

});
```

But it doesn't work. When I load the html page, there is only white. My thinking is that this is because it isn't grabbing the array within the JSON and using that data to populate the HTML directive I set up.

newsInfo.js:

```
app.directive('newsInfo',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
  info: '='
},
templateUrl:'newsInfo.html'
  };
    });
```

newsInfo.html:

```
<h2>{{ info.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ info.published }}</p>
```

My HTML doc is:

```
<head>      
    <title></title>

    <!--src for AngularJS library--> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="THE APP NAME"> <!--insert ng app here-->
    <div ng-controller="MainController"> <!--insert ng controller here-->
        <div ng-repeat="news in newsInfo"><!--insert ng repeat here-->
            <!-- directive goes here-->
            <newsInfo info="news"></newsInfo>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="MainController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="getNews.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="newsInfo.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: provide the code of html

Comment: Posting all code is relevant. Also, put something non related into the html will tell  you something as well. If it's still white, has nothing to do with the service.

Comment: without seeing your HTML page it's hard to say exactly what's occurring, but my first guess is that angular fails to load, because you have an error in your code.  the way you are calling your factory here seems strange to me.

Comment: so with that update, it's clear that if `newsInfo` is empty, you will not display anything.  Are you getting any error messages that might explain why `newsInfo` would be empty?

Comment: posted the HTML. If I replace the directive with a normal div and a test <p>, it shows up. So I guess it's on Angular's end. Also, what about the way I call my factory is weird?

Comment: wait, you'll have to explain that comment a bit more.  if you replace the `newsInfo` directive with a `<div>` you get the div repeated for the correct number of `news` items? or are you talking about you replaced the `ng-repeat`? also, it's completely possible that there is something wrong with the `newsInfo` directive, which isn't even shown here.

Comment: if i replace the directive underneath the div with ng-repeat with a placeholder div that has a <p>{{ news.title }}</p> and I load it in the browser, I get this: {{news.title}} displayed. So the browser is just reading that input as static text, not an angular value

Comment: @user262064 try `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com...` instead of `src="//ajax.googleapis.com` . I think angular is not being loaded

Comment: I would tend to agree that this sounds as though angular isn't loaded, especially if the expressions are rendering as `{{news.title}}`.  again, this goes back to the same question, do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: i'm using sublime text 2. if i open the console, it shows when I save.. would it also show errors? I've never tried to run anything on that text editor.

Comment: not error messages in your editor.  Error messages in the browser console window when you run the site(F12).  Chrome and Firefox tend to have better debug consoles than IE, just FYI.

Comment: wow thank you for pointing that out to me. Apparently I had to upload the newsInfo.html doc to an S3 bucket and use that URL as `“Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.”` But now Angular is blocking that external source with the: `Error: "$sce:insecurl Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked"`... I guess that AWS v. GAE shit runs deep...

Comment: so since the html template was so simple, i just bipassed this issue by typing in the template directly into the .js directive and it worked! thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am answering my own question, I should point out that everyone's answers were also correct. The code had multiple errors, but the final error was fixed by doing the following:

Apparently I had to upload the newsInfo.html doc to an S3 bucket and use that URL as `“Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.”` But then Angular blocked that external source with the Error: `"$sce:insecurl Processing of a Resource from Untrusted Source Blocked"`.

So since the html template was so simple, i just bipassed this issue by typing in the template directly into the .js directive and it worked! thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<newsInfo info="news"></newsInfo>
```

to

```
<news-info info="news"></news-info>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/bhv0zvhw/3/

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController"> <!--insert ng controller here-->
    <div ng-repeat="news in newsInfo"><!--insert ng repeat here-->
        <!-- directive goes here-->
        <newsInfo info="news"></newsInfo>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you are assigning correct data to the variable, as Martin Ciz suggested in the other answer `$scope.newsInfo = data.news;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getNews = function(){
    return $http.get('URL').success(function(data) { 
      return data.news; 
    })
};
```

^ This, just change it so that the success function returns only the news!